# Azure DevOps Testing

Tags: npm, file-upload, azure-devops, postman, newman

The basic purpose is to test a profile image upload API. I have an API which takes image file as an input and updates the profile picture according to given auth. I ran this API in postman and it was working fine. Now what I want to achieve is that I want to run this collection which has just one API for now on Azure devOps using npm, newman and publish test results. The issue that i am facing is that I can not find a way to upload that file. In postman collection, file path is the path in which your file is placed on your pc. In order to Run that api on devOps, what path should i give? Also, is there a way to upload an image or any sort of file?

Answer (score 0):

> In postman collection, file path is the path in which your file is
>   placed on your pc.

According to this description, you should want to upload the picture to a local file path.

The first thing that is clear is that you need to use the self-hosted agent to run the pipeline,because only if you use the agent installed on your local machine to run, you can track your local file path in Azure Devops. You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) on how to install a self-hosted agent.

Usually, the postman collection is exported as a `.json` file and then pushed it into the repo. If you set the file path in the collection, is it included in the collection.json?

In addition, it is difficult to reproduce your issue based on the information available, more detailed information is needed for further investigation:1. Which api are you using? 
 2.Postman collection settings 3.Specific operation process 4. Pipeline definition. It will be easier to understand in the form of screenshots.